# Sinch flash call : is it possible outside an android app?

Tags: sinch

I am trying to verify a user's phone (landline) by calling them and allowing them to enter a 4 digit code when prompted , thus verifying their phone. Is it possible via sinch ? As per their docs they only support a flash call and that too within an android app.

Comment: WE have launched that feature now, check out our docs http://sinch.com/docs/verification

Answer (score 0):

Or verification SDK does not have that right now (we are working on it) and will launch it soon. If you mail me I can give you some pre access if you want. christian@sinch.com